# Unable to uninstall locust from system

Tags: python, pip, locust

The current locust version is 2.1.0 I think I had installed it by `pip3 install locust`. It turns out I need the locust 1.2.2 version for my work project. Even after installing the locust 1.2.2 version, after running `locust -V` I get 2.1.0.

I have tried 'pip uninstall locust': it uninstalls the locust 1.2.2 version. Running it again gives the output `WARNING: Skipping locust as it is not installed.` same is the output for `pip3 uninstall locust`. I was thinking to remove the locust from the disk directory but `whereis locust` gives no output.

Can someone please suggest any solution? I'm using macOS Big Sur.

Comment: What happens if you `pip show locust`? I'm assuming nothing as you got the warning on uninstall.

Comment: Or try `which locust`... it may give you an installation folder

Comment: Thank @gmdev @Peter for your comments, `pip show locust` indicated that no package was found but on `which locust` gave the bin path from where I removed it.